# vue - custom blocks - syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**Vue** single file components enable to create **custom blocks** (apart from the well-known *script*, *template* and *style*). Official docs: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/custom-blocks.html#example But is there a way to get syntax highligting to work inside such a custom block? I tried inserting JS code as well as other lang types but there is no syntax highlighting.

Comment: Syntax highlighting depends on your IDE doesn't it? Chances are the extension/plugin you've installed does not recognize custom blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vetur supports syntax highlighting in a [custom block](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/highlighting.html#custom-block):

> Vetur provides a setting `vetur.grammar.customBlocks` that defaults to:
>
> ```json
> "vetur.grammar.customBlocks": {
>   "docs": "md",
>   "i18n": "json"
> }
> ```
>
> You can
>
> - Change `vetur.grammar.customBlocks`, for example:
>
> ```json
> "vetur.grammar.customBlocks": {
>   "docs": "md",
>   "i18n": "json",
>   "page-query": "graphql",
>   "static-query": "graphql"
> }
> ```
>
> - Run the command `Vetur: Generate grammar` from `vetur.grammar.customBlocks` (via the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette))
> - **Restart VS Code** to get syntax highlighting for custom > blocks.
>
> Valid language value for custom blocks:
>
> - All lang values in the support table.
> - `md` | `yaml` | `json` | `php` | `graphql`

Comment: Can you run the `Vetur: Generate grammar` command from a terminal in VScode? I keep getting the "command not found: Vetur" error and I've checked that the Vue Language Server is indeed running.... (Mac OS)

Comment: @songololo That command needs to be run from the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), not from a terminal/shell.